# Accessing wpa_supplicant using wpa_cli without sudo

Tags: networking, 18.04, sudo, wpa-supplicant

I am using wpa_supplicant service to connect with wifi networks in ubuntu 18.04. Its configuration file is as below.

```
ctrl_interface_group=sudo
ap_scan=1
fast_reauth=1
update_config=1
p2p_disabled=1
```

to communicate with wpa_supplicant i have to use wpa_cli with sudo. Is there another way by which i dont have to use sudo and still be able to connect with wifi networks.